# Importing files React Native

Tags: react-native

I am learning to import files into React Native. I am trying to import the User.js file into the App.js file, but it displays an error and I don't understand where I'm wrong. Help me please.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import User from "../Components/User";

export default function App() {
return (
<View>
<User/>
</View>
)};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

User.js

```
import React from "react";
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

let User = () => {
return <View>
<Text>Hello My Darling</Text>
</View>

export default User;

let styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: make sure that `../Components/User` is the correct relative path

Comment: @Kai, Yes, I'm sure. It imports automatically. My mistake is: 

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.


And shows the Users function in error. I don't understand where is my mistake

Comment: That sounds like a Babel or Metro config issue. Check the [template](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/template) and make sure those are set up correctly for React Native

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the bracker of your "User" export function.

```
import React from "react";
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

let User = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hello My Darling</Text>
        </View>
    );
}; // << close this bracket.

export default User;

let styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: I know, i tried to do it, but it doesn't help. The same mistake(((

Comment: Can you include the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Closing bracket of the 'User' function is missing. Currently, export statement is inside the functional component which is not allowed.